# Create a full screen GridView in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I want to create a full screen GridView control for a Metro Style application in Windows 8 that grows and adapts to the user changing their screen resolution.

I'm trying to imitate the calendar application on Windows 8, wen you swap the metro screen between monitors, the size of each square (date) changes so that the screen is always filled.

Typically you would have a fluid `ItemTemplate` I need to ensure that the whole screen is full, so sometimes the GridView items will be small (when running on a tablet) and sometimes they will be large (when running on my Desktop).

Can I achieve this using XAML or do I have to get funky with changing the `ItemTemplate` for the GridView when the screen size changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control in other xaml frameworks that does what you want is called UniformGrid. It let you specify the number of Rows or Columns and then sized each child item to the appropriate size.

UniformGrid currently doesn't appear in the WinRT xaml stack, but it's not difficult to port (I have done it once but don't have access to the source). You can get the source for the Silverlight version from [Jeff Wilcox - Uniform Grid](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/01/uniform-grid/).

For a calendar style app you'll have a uniform grid for the rows and then each row will have one for the columns..

Comment: That's annoying, I will hunt around and see what I can find

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to place the GridView in a Grid, and that should take care of flexible layout. As long as the Grid is the root element of the page that you assign to `Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current` property, and the GridView is the only child of the Grid, it should stretch horizontally and vertically to fill the screen.

To get a Calendar-type look, you can put the GridView in the second row of the Grid, and have the title etc on the first row.

Comment: Yeah, this is OK, I can do that part, what I want is to make sure all the items in the GridView fill the page but do not extend beyond it, so the ItemsTemplate which is just an empty grid for now must have width and height properties that need to change based on the screen resolution, does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [Viewbox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx).